# If an input is part of a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm stuck on this part of a code. Here is an example of a sample text

```
items = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
choice = input("Input variable here: ")
if choice != items:
    print("Item not found")
else:
    print("Item found")
```

That is an example of what I'd like to do. I want to work out if what the user has inputted in is part of a given list. This is python 3.5

Comment: Should be `if choice not in items`. If `items` is large, you'd be better off making it a set, i.e. `items = {}`

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response but that didn't work, it always outputs 'Item not found'.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the content of the value, and not just its name?

Comment: Chris's code will work if the data in `items` are strings. If Neill's answer doesn't fix your problem you should post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is going to depend on the type of data in the list. `input` returns everything as `str`. So if the list data type is `float` then the if statement will evaluate as `True`. For `int` data use the following:

```
items = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
choice = input("Input variable here: ")
if int(choice) not in items:
    print("Item not found")
else:
    print("Item found")
```

for `float` is must be:

```
items = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
choice = input("Input variable here: ")
if float(choice) not in items:
    print("Item not found")
else:
    print("Item found")
```

This should now correctly evaluate the if statement.